# How do I convert a ResourceId variable into a string in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, azure

I'm having trouble into converting a ResourceID into a String in PowerShell.

I have a list that have every virtual interface information from an Azure Subscription.

```
$virtualInterfaceArray = @(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface)
```

Then I put the value of an Index of that list into a variable, so I cant get the exact information I want. For example:

```
$hostVirtualInterfaceIndex = $virtualInterfaceArray[5]
$hostVirtualInterfaceVM = hostVirtualInterfaceIndex.VirtualMachine
```

If I print $hostVirtualInterfaceVM it returns:

```
PS C:\Users\marcelo.salvatori> $hostVirtualInterfaceVM
Id                                                                                                                                 
--                                                                                                                                 
/subscriptions/301238dsf0sdfj/resourceGroups/rg-test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmtest
```

I know that I can't use the .Split() method, because it is not a String. So I try to contert it using the .ToString() method:

```
PS C:\Users\marcelo.salvatori> $hostVirtualInterfaceVMString = hostVirtualInterfaceVM.ToString()
```

But then, when I print the variable, it returns:

```
PS C:\Users\marcelo.salvatori> $hostVirtualInterfaceVMString
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSResourceId
```

I need this conversation so I can use the .Split() method.

Comment: `$hostVirtualInterfaceVMString = hostVirtualInterfaceVM.ID`

Comment: Or without the intermediate vars `(Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface)[5].VirtualMachine.ID` not usable if you need to lookup other values.

Comment: LotPings, I am not sure this will work... I've tried something similiar that didn't.

Comment: Actually, EBGreen seemed like it gave the solution, but it returns the NIC name, no the Virtual Machine's name associated with that NIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the Virtual Machine's name associated with that NIC. Please have a try to use the following code.

```
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface |  Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name="VMName";Expression = {$_.VirtualMachine.Id.tostring().substring($_.VirtualMachine.Id.tostring().lastindexof('/')+1)}}
```

Comment: Would you mind explain me this piece of code? It Returns both NIC and VM name, not only the VM name.

Comment: You could use `-property` to select the proerties that you want. For more information, please refer to [select-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Based on this code I could make a few changes to get what I want.